# How to calculate distances between vertices in Geometry nodes so that they remain at zero after

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want a moving object to affect the rotation of instances so that they rotate when the object gets closer but don't return to their original stance when the object has traversed, which is what happens if I use Geometry Proximity.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this example:

[image]

1. In order to get tiles "remember" previous position, you have to use simulation zone.

[image]

I subtracted a new rotation from the current one and apply it only if it is positive. So that tiles will rotate only one way.

2. For getting proper distance, I need only location of the Empty, no need to use proximity node for that. (Maybe your setup requires proximity node, I don't know) After getting the distance between tile and Empty, I divide it by its scale, so that scale will change the effect.

[image]

[image]